# Counting values within levels

Tags: r, intervals, r-factor

I have a set of levels in R that I generate with `cut`, e.g. say fractional values between 0 and 1, broken down into 0.1 bins:

```
> frac <- cut(c(0, 1), breaks=10)
> levels(frac)
[1] "(-0.001,0.1]" "(0.1,0.2]"    "(0.2,0.3]"    "(0.3,0.4]"    "(0.4,0.5]"
[6] "(0.5,0.6]"    "(0.6,0.7]"    "(0.7,0.8]"    "(0.8,0.9]"    "(0.9,1]"
```

Given a vector `v` containing continuous values between `[0.0, 1.0]`, how do I count the frequency of elements in `v` that fall within each level in `levels(frac)`?

I could customize the number of breaks and/or the interval from which I am making levels, so I'm looking for a way to do this with standard R commands, so that I can build a two-column data frame: one column for the levels as factors, and the second column for a fractional or percentage value of total elements in `v` over the level.

Note: The following does not work:

```
> table(frac)
frac
(-0.001,0.1]    (0.1,0.2]    (0.2,0.3]    (0.3,0.4]    (0.4,0.5]    (0.5,0.6]
           1            0            0            0            0            0
   (0.6,0.7]    (0.7,0.8]    (0.8,0.9]      (0.9,1]
           0            0            0            1
```

If I use `cut` on `v` directly, then I do not get the same levels when I run `cut` on different vectors, because the range of values — their minimum and maximum — is going to be different between arbitrary vectors, and so while I may have the same number of breaks, the level intervals will not be the same.

My goal is to take different vectors and bin them to the same set of levels. Hopefully this helps clarify my question. Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
frac = seq(0,1,by=0.1)

ranges = paste(head(frac,-1), frac[-1], sep=" - ")
freq   = hist(v, breaks=frac, include.lowest=TRUE, plot=FALSE)

data.frame(range = ranges, frequency = freq$counts)
```

Comment: That is an *extremely* roundabout way of achieving this.

Comment: Thanks, this gets me back a vector I can work with directly.

Comment: @AlexReynolds Not to be petulant but you’ve accepted the easily worst answer out of the three here.

Comment: It correctly answers the question and returns an object with attributes I can access directly. If you want to say it is wrong, that's your choice, but you might explain why before voting it down. Or not, that's your choice, too.

Comment: @AlexReynolds My first comment on this answer explains why: it’s conceptually very complex. It computes a full histogram that’s meant to be plotted (which the code explicitly needs to disable); *incidentally*, this also produces the result you’re looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Amend `frac` to actually represent your desired intervals, and then use the `table` function:

```
x = runif(100) # For example.
frac = cut(x, breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1))
table(frac)
```

Result:

```
frac
  (0,0.1] (0.1,0.2] (0.2,0.3] (0.3,0.4] (0.4,0.5] (0.5,0.6] (0.6,0.7] (0.7,0.8]
       14         9         8        10         8        12         7         7
(0.8,0.9]   (0.9,1]
       16         9
```

Comment: To be more specific, I want to count an arbitrary vector across a given set of levels. This does not do that.

Comment: @AlexReynolds Check now. I’ve fixed my answer. I had blindly assumed that the intervals were correct … but they weren’t. Note the negative value you’re getting at the leftmost side.

Comment: I am using `cut` as the instructions are described in `?cut`. If I pass it the vector `c(0,1)` then I am puzzled as to why it makes an interval with a negative value. Perhaps it is a bug in R, or is an error from machine precision.

Comment: @AlexReynolds it is not a bug, round bracket means "do not include", to have 0 to be included it adds negative minimum value.

Comment: @AlexReynolds The documentation explains why, though: “the outer limits are moved away by 0.1% of the range to ensure that the extreme values both fall within the break intervals.” It also explains the usage in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Introduce extremes `c(0, 1)` to `v` then use the same `cut`:

```
library(dplyr)

#dummy data
set.seed(1)
v <- round(runif(7), 2)

#result
data.frame(v,
           vFrac = cut(c(0, 1, v), breaks = 10)[-c(1, 2)]) %>% 
  group_by(vFrac) %>% 
  mutate(vFreq = n())

# Source: local data frame [10 x 3]
# Groups: vFrac [8]
# 
#        v        vFrac vFreq
#    <dbl>       <fctr> <int>
# 1   0.27    (0.2,0.3]     1
# 2   0.37    (0.3,0.4]     1
# 3   0.57    (0.5,0.6]     1
# 4   0.91      (0.9,1]     2
# 5   0.20    (0.1,0.2]     1
# 6   0.90    (0.8,0.9]     1
# 7   0.94      (0.9,1]     2
```

Comment: No need to introduce extreme values, or to remove the anything afterwards, if you specify the breaks explicitly.

Comment: @KonradRudolph agreed, just trying to follow OP's logic, re-use factor levels from other factor object (not sure if this even makes sense).

Answer (score 1):

Use findInterval instead of cut:

```
v<-data.frame(v=runif(100,0,1))

library(plyr)
v$x<-findInterval(v$v,seq(0,1,by=0.1))*0.1
ddply(v, .(x), summarize, n=length(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
frac = seq(0, 1, 0.1)
set.seed(42); v = rnorm(10, 0.5, 0.2)
sapply(1:(length(frac)-1), function(i) sum(frac[i]<v & frac[i+1]>=v))
#[1] 0 0 0 1 3 2 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well also. Not sure who is voting things down.