# group age in intervals to create a contingency table with another variable in r

Tags: r

[this is the contingency table that I'm trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0wGO.png)

data:

```
  Edad  influye
1     31     Nada
2     72     Poco
3     34     Poco
4     47     Poco
5     74     Poco
6     27     Poco
7     43 Moderado
8     58     Poco
9     42     Nada
10    69 Moderado
11    73     Poco
12    48 Moderado
13    38     Poco
14    44     Poco
15    46     Poco
```

the real data have 247 row´s

with the function `cut` I can create the intervals, but when I try to create the contingency table I can not do it, some suggestion

this are the intervals

```
[16,24.5] (24.5,33] (33,41.5] (41.5,50] (50,58.5] (58.5,67] (67,75.5] (75.5,84] 
        1        10        38        59        59        44        27         9
```

Comment: I am not sure this is what you mean, have you tried `table(cut(df$Edad, c(16,24.5,33,41.5,50, 58.5,67,75.5,84)))`? or check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42541994/counting-values-within-levels]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, it has helped me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `table()`:

```
R> set.seed(1)
R> df = data.frame(
  Edad = sample(1:100, 15),
  Influye = c( "Nada", "Poco", "Poco", "Poco", "Poco", "Poco", "Moderado", "Poco", "Nada", "Moderado", "Poco", "Moderado", "Poco", "Poco", "Poco")
)
R> head(table(df))
    Influye
Edad Moderado Nada Poco
  6         1    0    0
  16        1    0    0
  19        0    0    1
  20        0    0    1
  27        0    1    0
  34        0    0    1
R> table(df[1])
 6 16 19 20 27 34 37 57 58 61 62 67 86 89 97
 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
R> table(df[2])
Moderado     Nada     Poco 
       3        2       10
```

With cuts:

```
R> table(cut(df$Edad, breaks=seq(10,100,10)), df$Influye)
           Moderado Nada Poco
  (10,20]         1    0    2
  (20,30]         0    1    0
  (30,40]         0    0    2
  (40,50]         0    0    0
  (50,60]         0    1    1
  (60,70]         0    0    3
  (70,80]         0    0    0
  (80,90]         0    0    2
  (90,100]        1    0    0
```

I'm not sure what the extra numbers in your picture are supposed to represent.

Comment: your answer is very useful